# Resistive Screen Zooming Option for PDF files

Tags: touchscreen, pdf

I'm looking to buy a resistive screen android tablet for reading PDFs. Is there an app that lets resistive tablets to zoom into the text for a PDF file? Or is their a specific resistive screen for it I heard there was a 2 point and 5 point but not entirely sure or are all resistive screens the same.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resistive touch and Capacitive touch will operate the apps the same way, the same way a laser and a mechanical mouse are two different technologies designed to do the same thing for the user. Both have their advantages and disadvantages, for instance try using your capacitive iphone screen with gloves or finger nails, it wont work. A capacitive screens are known to be more accurate in general, although some nokia n900 users would argue that point. If you are buying a cheap tablet, I would not expect a resistive screen to be as accurate or responsive as a capacitive screen used on most mainstream models out there.

You should be able to pan zoom even if the screen only supported "2 points" multitouch I wouldn't stress about that. All PDF viewers will be compatible its a matter of trying a few out for yourself one by one, probably start with the official Adobe PDF Reader and go from there, everyone will have different tastes in what they want from a pdf viewer app.

Keep reading if you are still interested, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchscreen#Technologies

Comment: Thanks, that was my main question if a resistive screen would be able to pan zoom into a PDF file. Since I find no reason to pay $700 for just using a tablet for reading PDFs thats why I was looking at a cheap 10.2" resistive tablet. If I would use it for something else ofcourse wouldn't mind paying for Mot. Xoom put I have no use for it other than for my PDF files to read to replace my Mac Air for convenience.

Comment: No probs, but I would rather go for something like a nook color with a warranty than some other cheap tablet made to be nothing but well, cheap. A nook should be around the same price point just a slightly smaller screen http://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/nook-color-barnes-noble/1100437663 These things are also designed to make them money through the book stores etc as well as being cheap, which is an ok compromise ;)